# BASH: MV always leaves 1 file behind

Tags: bash, macos, mv

I usually `cp` from $A to $B, and then `mv` into Backup from $A to $C. As such, I never actually delete the files. But the problem is that 80% of the time I would get 1 image stuck behind in $A.

Either of these, gets at least 1 image stuck:

```
cp "$A" "$B"
mv "$A" "$C"
```

```
find "$f" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \;
find "$f" -type f -exec mv -f {} "$TodaysDate" \;
```

```
find "$f" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \; && \
find "$f" -type f -exec mv -f {} "$TodaysDate" \;
```

What I currently use:

```
TodaysDate="/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/WIP/$(date +%Y-%m-%d) DA/"
RedTag="xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "0000000000000000000C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000""
MainServer="/Volumes/Hams Hall Workspace/ReToucher3_WIP"

ServerImageFlow=/Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/ServerImageFlow/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
outfile="$ServerImageFlow"/$(whoami)-WIP.csv


#Move Images into Retouchers Folder, log anything moved and copy into desktop
if [[ ! -d "$TodaysDate" ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/12 Mannequin"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/13 Drop Neck"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/15 Jewellery and White Products Scarfs Socks"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/20 Tops"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/22 Bulk Items"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/24 Shoes Sunglasses Cosmetics"
    mkdir -p "$TodaysDate/36 Toys Home Decorations SS1"

    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/12 Mannequin"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/13 Drop Neck"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/15 Jewellery and White Products Scarfs Socks"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/20 Tops"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/22 Bulk Items"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/24 Shoes Sunglasses Cosmetics"
    $RedTag "$TodaysDate/36 Toys Home Decorations SS1"

    while read f ; do
        basename "$f" >> "$outfile"
        find "$f" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \; && \
        mv -f "$f" "$TodaysDate"
    done

else

    while read f ; do
        basename "$f" >> "$outfile"
        find "$f" -type f -exec cp -p {} "$MainServer" \; && \
        mv -f "$f" "$TodaysDate"
    done

fi
```

I also tried to `cp` first and then `mv`, `mv -f` or even `rm`. But it still leaves 1 file behind. With `find` it is the same. I tried adding a small `sleep` to let `cp` move all of its file before `mv` which didn't help. Logical operators seem to help, but ever so slightly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The code I use is above. Images/files can be any files, irrespective. Everything is happening within the same shared network (restarting does nothing).

Comment: Include a [mre].

Comment: Edited to add full-script in question. Images/files can be any files irrespective.

Comment: Maybe you can check the exit code of the `mv` command in case you can retry again when fails?

Comment: Thanks @Victor for the advice! I will test it today, and if it works will edit the post with adjusted script! So far it worked perfectly on 5 different tries. I can see it always struggles to move the last file, as it starts renaming it to .afpDeleted, but eventually on the next try it moves it!! I will keep you posted.

Comment: what is $f ? what is the input going into `while read f ; do`.

Comment: Drop the `-f` in `mv -f` and observe if you get any error message from `mv`.  Also, `[! -d "$TodaysDate"]` should have been `[ ! -d "$TodaysDate" ]`

Comment: @Orion $f are the selected items. So it backs-up not all folder, but the selection.

Comment: if you add `echo $f` at the start of the while loop are all the filenames printed?

Comment: You already went wrong with `cp $A $B`. You should double-quote shell variables `cp "$A" "$B"`.

Comment: check your code at https://shellcheck.net and be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever) as your first line. Good luck.

Comment: The file that is "stuck" was it there before your script started?  Wildcard extensions are processed first, then the command is executed.  So if new files are created after the expansion, `cp` of `find` will not know about this new file.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin fixed still issue persists @Orion `echo $f` outputs all files @Mark Setchell in the original script I used `""` @shelter shellcheck.net shows everything is good @Nic3500 yep, files might have been between 5min-1day before I move them.  So far @Victor suggestion worked, e.g.: to simply retry `mv` if it fails. Although, it takes now 10x longer to run it. So I am better off simply using the old script and just deleting the stuck file. Also issue usually appears when moving 10Gb+, smaller sizes move just fine